# ActiveRecord where OR clause. Can equal nil or a time earlier than Time.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Food` model with an `expired_at` field. If the food is not expired, the `expired_at` field is set to nil. If it is expired, the field is set to a time earlier than Time.now. It can be set to a time in the future, and the food is not expired yet.

If I'm trying to write a scope that gives me back non-expired food, what can I do? I want something like:

```
scope :non_expired, -> { where(expired_at: nil OR expired_at > Time.now)
```

The above doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using rails version less than 5, there is no support for or.
For exmaple
Rails 4

```
scope :non_expired, ->{ where('expired_at = ? OR expired_at >', nil, Time.now) }
```

Rails 5

```
{ where('expired_at = ?', nil).or(Food.where('expired_at > ?', Time.now) }
```

Comment: You probably want: where('expired_at is null OR expired_at > ?', Time.now)